# Occupation Report with Capacities

Tags: python, excel, powerbi

I've come across a situation at our work where we need to create a report to measure our field service staff occupation for the future (as a forecast).

We have all the data at SAP as the example below, extracted as an excel sheet:

[image]

We need to calculate how many Man Days (column C) we have per month (start date and end date) and per work center (column G), and also by activity type (column J). Per month we have a calculation where we have the number of working days in a month multiplied by the number of employees. The idea is to have a bar chart with a line representing the capacity.

It is possible to do this manually but i'm trying to find a more practical way because today it is an extremely manual job with copy and paste all over the place. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this with Python or even Power BI?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.